# Pegar valor de um radio no jquery cakephp

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

Em meu código tenho um radio e gostaria de pegar a opção selecionada em uma variável na minha função jquery.

**Input do botão:**

```
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('attendance_status_id', array(
          'type' => 'radio',
          'options' => $attendance_statuses,
          'div' => array('id' => 'attendance-statuses', 'class' => 'attendance_statuses'),
          'legend' => '',
          'label' => true
          ));
          ?>
```

**Script em que quero recebe-lo:**

```
    $("#attendance-statuses").change(function(){
  var obs = $('input[name = attendance_status_id]:checked').serialize();
  console.log(obs);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    data: 
    {obs, 
    obsEntity: 1
    },
    url: "<?php echo Router::url('/observations/observation_options'); ?>",
    success:function(dados){
      dados = JSON.parse(dados);
      var $el = $("#obs-select");
      $('#obs-select option:gt(0)').remove();
      $.each(dados, function(value,key) {
        $el.append($("<option></option>")
           .attr("value", value).text(key));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repara que este objeto está mal formatado:

```
data: {
    obs, 
    obsEntity: 1
},
```

devia ser

```
data: {
    obs: obs,   // <-- faltava-te "valor" dessa "chave" do par chave/valor
    obsEntity: 1
},
```

Uma vez que os `radio` buttons só podem ser escolhidos um de cada vez também podias ter:

```
// usei ".val()" em vez de ".serialize()"
var obs = $('input[name = attendance_status_id]:checked').val();
```

e no AJAX:

```
data: {
    attendance_status_id: obs, 
    obsEntity: 1
},
```

mas é uma questão de preferência e nem sei como estás a fazer no PHP para receber esse POST.

Comment: Funcionou aqui, obrigado